# Why aren't my dictionaries being added to my array? indexPath.row returns nil

Tags: swift

I'm getting an error: `let video = videos[indexPath.row]`*Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value.* This means none of the two dictionaries are in the array `videos`.

I thought it might be trying to get the indexPath.row before the dictionaries are added to the array, so I removed that code from `viewDidLoad` and put it at the top inside `tableView`. That didn't work so I'm guessing there must be something wrong with how I defined the array `var videos: [Video]` or there is something wrong with how I'm setting the data to the array `self.videos.append(video)`. I know `video` has data because I printed `video.name` and `video.link` and it gave the correct data for those.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseFirestore

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    var player = AVPlayer()
    var playerViewContoller = AVPlayerViewController()
    var db: Firestore!
    var videos: [Video]!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoCell", for: indexPath) as! VideoTableViewCell

        let video = videos[indexPath.row] // unexpectedly found nil
        cell.video = video
        return cell

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection("videos").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let docRef = self.db.collection("videos").document(document.documentID)
                    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                        if let video = document.flatMap({
                            $0.data().flatMap({ (data) in
                                return Video(dictionary: data)
                            })
                        }) {
                            self.videos.append(video)

                        } else {
                            print("Document does not exist")
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }

}


public struct Video {

    let name: String
    let link: String

    init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.name = dictionary["name"] as! String
        self.link = dictionary["link"] as! String
    }
}
```

The array `videos` should have each of the dictionaries I added to it when this code runs `self.videos.append(video)` but, instead it shows an error.

Comment: You never initialize `videos`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't append to a nil array. First define it as an empty array of videos.

`var videos: [Video] = [Video]()`

Comment: This wasn't the only issue. I'm appending the items to what seems to be an instance of the array inside a closure. I need a way to append the items to the array I defined in the scope of the class because I have other functions that need to access this data.

Comment: It's not a scope issue. It's timing. The closure is async, so when you assign the array as the datasource for the tableView it's still empty. Try adding a tableview insert after each append, or just reload the tableView once the for loop ends.